# Strange default zoom in Firefox 22.0

Tags: firefox

I have a completely fresh installation of Firefox 22.0 on Windows 7 and I just opened a website.

The website appeared to be zoomed (fonts as well as images) so I hit Strg+0 with no effect. I tried other websites and it was the same - they were all zoomed.

Compared with Chrome where everything is looking fine, in Firefox images and fonts are magnified!

Any pointers on what is going on here? How can I switch this off?

[image]

Comment: A keyboard-shortcut to set the zoom to 0 which means "no zoom"

Comment: its CTRL+0 in english

Comment: could it be, that the zoom in firefox is 100%, but the zooom in chrome is at 85% ? did you hit strg/ctrl+0 in chrome too ?

Comment: the zoom in chrome is 100% and how it's supposed to be. e.g. when i take a screenshot of a website i built in chrome and compare it with the corresponding photoshop file the pixels align perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this behavior is caused by the fact that from version 22 Firefox takes into account the font size set in the OS (e.g. "125%" corresponding to 120dpi). There is some info on Mozilla support forums:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962945

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963211

Answer (score 4):

1) Type **"about:config:** in address bar 
2) search for **"layout.css.devPixelsPerPx"** 
3) change value of **"layout.css.devPixelsPerPx"** from **-1.0 to 1.0**