# Why firefox displays table border differently than IE and Chromium?

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, border

I use [Datables](http://www.datatables.net/) to show a table of data.
It does work correctly but Firefox show every n rows a thicker border :
[image: table display example in firefox]

Is it a *"Firefox Features"* to make table more readable ? or is it maybe a css bug ? 
When I check with firebug, every row and cell have the exact same border size and CSS (except for the color).

```
 see the jsfiddle example
```

I also have the same issue with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cw82J/)

I try on IE 8 Chromium Opera ... and firefox seems to be the only one to have such a problem.

---

**Edit 1**:
I do not succed in using any solution in the so called duplicate thread.

- The zoom factor is set to 100% (no zoom)
- I use Firefox 24.

---

**Edit 2**:
Again no solution from the possible duplicate worked, and this is very strange, because if I use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>mouse scroll down</kbd> (zoom out) only once then it show me the table correctly, and if I simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset zoom then I have that strange border.

---

**Edit 3**:

```
<table aria-describedby="mainTable_info" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 100%;" class="dataTable" id="mainTable" frame="box" rules="all">

    <tbody aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" role="alert">
    <tr id="1603" class="odd PRODUCTREJECTED"><td class="">1603</td><td class="">tjyhhyytj</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">61429</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number1</a></td><td class="">poney2</td><td class=""></td><td class="">PRODUCT REJECTED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-07-08 13:28:07</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1602" class="even DEPLOYMENTREQUEST"><td class="">1602</td><td class="">tyjytjhtyjn</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">61364</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number2</a></td><td class="">poney42</td><td class=""></td><td class="">DEPLOYMENT REQUEST</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-07-08 13:13:43</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1600" class="odd PRODUCTREJECTED"><td class="">1600</td><td class="">sdfsdfsd</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">61342</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number3</a></td><td class="">poney42</td><td class=""></td><td class="">PRODUCT REJECTED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-07-08 12:46:06</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1597" class="even DEPLOYMENTREQUEST"><td class="">1597</td><td class="">azeazee</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">61424</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number4</a></td><td class="">poney42</td><td class=""></td><td class="">DEPLOYMENT REQUEST</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-07-02 08:35:51</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1582" class="odd PRODUCTREJECTED"><td class="">1582</td><td class="">azerzaraze</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">61289</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number5</a></td><td class="">poney42</td><td class=""></td><td class="">PRODUCT REJECTED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-06-20 10:27:15</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1579" class="even DEPLOYED"><td class="">1579</td><td class="">azerzrzerz</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">61159</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number6</a></td><td class="">poney2</td><td class=""><a href="documentation2" target="_blank">SOS_GWBATCH.docx</a></td><td class="">DEPLOYED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-06-14 12:14:39</td><td class=""></td><td class=""><a href="dvdvd" target="_blank">7091504</a></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1578" class="odd DEPLOYED"><td class="">1578</td><td class="">zefrzerfezr</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">61295</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number7</a></td><td class="">poney2</td><td class=""><a href="documentation1" target="_blank">SOS_GWBATCH.docx</a></td><td class="">DEPLOYED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-06-14 11:23:29</td><td class=""></td><td class=""><a href="vdvdvdv" target="_blank">7091068</a></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1577" class="even PRODUCTREJECTED"><td class="">1577</td><td class="">azdaeazeaz</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">60073</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number8</a></td><td class="">poney1</td><td class=""></td><td class="">PRODUCT REJECTED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-06-14 10:08:12</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1576" class="odd PRODUCTREJECTED"><td class="">1576</td><td class="">ededededed</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">58542</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number9</a></td><td class="">poney1</td><td class=""></td><td class="">PRODUCT REJECTED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-06-14 10:07:38</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
    <tr id="1574" class="even PRODUCTREJECTED"><td class="">1574</td><td class="">dddddddd</td><td class="">POP</td><td class="">60765</td><td class=""><a href="http://cscscscscs.fr" target="_blank">delivery_number10</a></td><td class="">poney1</td><td class=""></td><td class="">PRODUCT REJECTED</td><td class=" sorting_1">2013-06-14 09:42:37</td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td><td class=""></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox?

Comment: Did you make basic css reset?

Comment: Also in my case The zoom factor is not responisble for the strange border

Comment: I have the exact same behavior on the jsfiddle where there is no CSS at all. But i wiil (thought it will be difficult as I use JQuery UI plus some addons

Comment: Please paste your fiddle code into your question. Do not try to circumvent it - it just makes your question look silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive it's an effect of rounding. I can only reproduce it in Firefox by zooming out or in a few steps from the default. The attached screenshot looks like it may be zoomed in a few steps.

Maybe your default zoom level is changed somehow causing the default to be zoomed in somewhat? (Not sure if PPI/DPI settings in the OS may affect it too).

EDIT:
It seems that PPI setting may indeed change the default zoom: [Strange default zoom in Firefox 22.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466974/strange-default-zoom-in-firefox-22-0)